# Keyboard Extension is deleted from settings after app update

Tags: ios, app-store

Suppose we have an iOS app with keyboard extension (custom keyboard). User downloads the app and installs the keyboard (enables it in system settings). After it a new version of the app releases. User updates the app. And then, *after 3-15 minutes* since the update **keyboard removed!** It doesn't appears in the keyboards list in the settings and user should add it again.

This is very bad user experience and I need find a way to fix it. I have no ideas why it happens in this particular app, we have other keyboard-app on Appstore and that app updates properly.